# R-Cran attempt to change an attribute to NULL Smote

Tags: r

I am using the following CRAN package *DMwR* to deal with the problem of imbalanced data :
Code is the following:

```
require(DMwR)
dm = read.table("C:/data/exampleData.txt", sep=",")
ncols<-ncol(dm)
dm<-cbind(dm[2:ncols],dm[1])
dmSmote<-SMOTE(target ~ . , dm,k=5,perc.over = 1400,perc.under=140)
dm<-cbind(dmSmote[ncols],dmSmote[1:ncols-1])
```

Data :

```
5.901487,5.176487,1
6.917943,3.979710,0
5.247007,3.628324,1
5.157673,6.212658,0
4.836749,3.978392,0
4.590970,5.547353,0
3.895904,5.350865,0
4.312977,3.853151,0
5.844978,5.450767,0
4.009195,5.108031,0
```

**Column 1** = variable 1, **column 2** = variable 2, **column 3** = Class

---

I am getting the following error: ***attempt to change an attribute to NULL***

Link to library : http://cran.fhcrc.org/web/packages/DMwR/DMwR.pdf

What am I not getting right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classifier variable (`target` in your code) needs to be a factor.

```
require(DMwR)
## data
dm = structure(
    c(5.901487, 6.917943, 5.247007, 5.157673, 4.836749, 
        4.59097, 3.895904, 4.312977, 5.844978, 4.009195, 5.176487, 3.97971, 
        3.628324, 6.212658, 3.978392, 5.547353, 5.350865, 3.853151, 5.450767, 
        5.108031, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    .Dim = c(10L, 3L), 
    .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL))
dm = data.frame(dm)

## column names
colnames(dm) = c("var1", "var2", "target")

## you must convert the classifier variable to a factor
dm$target = factor(dm$target)

## SMOTE algorithm
dmSmote <- SMOTE(target ~ ., data = dm, k = 5,perc.over = 1400, perc.under = 140)
```

Using `debug()` on the function in question is a good starting point for diagnosing errors.